# Fill screen with image, center left-to-right with CSS

Tags: css

If I fill a screen with an image, like this:

```
width:auto;
height:100%;
```

That fills the screen vertically, and almost all screens horizontally. However, it also crops the image off the right side.

Is it possible to have the image float centered on the screen? So that left and right sides are cropped off equally? I would need a negative margin-left or something, but since I don't know how many pixels to do that, not sure if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For centering an unknown offset width in the screen, you can use a wrapper absolute div, placed in the center of the page.

Then, set the image absoluted positioned at `-50%` of its parent wrapper div. It will be perfectly in the middle, regardless the width, keeping the image's ratio.

```
<div id="imagewrapper">
    <img src="" id="image" />
</div>

#imagewrapper {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
}

#image {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Comment: I think something is not quite right here, or I am not doing something quite right. I end up with horizontal scrolling. I believe the wrapper is positioned correctly left-to-right, but the image it way too wide.

Comment: @BBDesign - Ops... sorry. Make the `#imagewrapper` a `position: fixed` instead of absolute, so it won't create the scrollbar

Comment: That helps, thanks, and I am close. I am having trouble at very narrow window widths, though... I wonder if there is a maximum amount that the browser will reduce an image.